# Как сделать POST запрос на сервер с обязательным параметром ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

Нужно сделать POST запрос на сервер, с обязательным параметром actionName, значением MessagesLoad.
мой код:

```
const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        body: {actionName: 'MessagesLoad'},
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://f0665380.xsph.ru', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setItems(result)
                },
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setError(error)
                }
            )
    }, [])
```

В приложении выдаёт следующую ошибку:
Error: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: А параметр точно должен быть в теле запроса? Может всё-таки в URL?

Comment: В postman сделал запрос, указал параметры в body, все пришло

Comment: Ну покажите что вы делали в postman-е

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать с помощью FormData

```
 const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('actionName', 'MessagesLoad')

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        body: formData,
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://f0665380.xsph.ru/', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setItems(result)
                },
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setError(error)
                }
            )
    }, [])
```